# routerLinkActive for multiple routes

Tags: angular

I want to apply 'active' class to my header nav bar. it is working well with the standard [`routerLinkActive`] but there is one issue. some of the `<li>` elements has two situations which makes them active.

I have `[/something/inboxes]` and `[/something/details/:Id]` and i want the `something` tab to be active for these two routes

this is my code:

```
  <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['/something/inboxes']">something</a>
  </li>
```

Note that the inboxes and details are completely different components.

My question is, is there any better and easier way than using `[ngClass]`

Comment: Change the route definition from /something/inboxes to /something. Or add a route /something that redirects to /something/inboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might help: [Angular4 - Is routerLinkActive only works on the same html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376598/angular4-is-routerlinkactive-only-works-on-the-same-html-tag)

Comment: the default [routerLinkActiveOptions] exact is always false.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I wanted link to be active for all child routes. I resolved it like this:
HTML:

```html
<a class="{YOUR CLASS}" routerLink="/{my link}/test" [class.selected]="isActive('{my link}')"><a>
```

If you have a different class for link active use [class.my-active-link-class]

TS:

```
 public isActive(url): boolean {
      return this.router.url.includes(url);
    }
```

You can extend your isActive method to accept array of urls.